# Timeloop short story from F&SF where loops get shorter and shorter

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Trying to ID a short story which appeared in one of the Magazine of Fantasy and Science Fiction's anthologies in the 1980s (IIRC) where the protagonist (and the entire world) was on a traffic island trapped in a timeloop which became steadily shorter and shorter on each go-round, from hours to minutes and then to seconds, until the loops were so short he couldn't even complete a thought, before the loop reset itself. The protagonist speculates that the Earth might have somehow fallen into a singularity or that time itself had ended because the universe was imploding.

Comment: The premise is very close to "Escapement" by Ballard, but that's much older than the 1980s.

Comment: I wonder if you have conflated two Ballard stories. *Concrete Island* is about a man trapped on a traffic island after an accident, but there is no time loop. *Escapement* is about a man in a time loop that does get shorter and shorter, but it takes place in his living room not on a traffic island.

Comment: @JohnRennie - In Concrete Island the protagonist muses that he may be stuck in some sort of alternate reality or time loop